# Propositional Logic, Precedence and Prioritising

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Morning, afternoon or evening depending on where you are from.

I have the following statement:

```
  !p&&(q||r)
```

The parenthesised statement (q||r) goes first then the ! then the && I believe.

If I wanted to say !(the whole statement) is !(p&&(q||r)) valid? so the person reading knows I am saying not the whole statement.

Doing this however changes the order of precedence I think. chaining the order to || then && then ! or am I wrong.

id like to keep the same order of precedence.

Comment: If you use parentheses, we assume that the initial negation sign "acts" only on the propositional variable $p$. If so, the formula is $(\lnot p) \land (q \lor r)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct:

Without those outside parentheses, !p&&(q||r) will be understood as (!p)&&(q||r)

So if you want to have the negation apply to the whole of the rest of the sentence, instead of just p, you have to use extra parentheses: !(p&&(q||r))

Answer (score 0):

This depends on context.  An answer and a comment that I've seen here work for some people's intended meaning, but in other contexts neither !(p&&(q||r)) nor !p&&(q||r) is well-formed, nor an abbreviation for a well-formed formula, even given that ! means logical negation, && means logical conjunction, and || means logical disjunction.  It would work out better to know the formation rules and know what abbreviations can get used.